# PyImport_Import returns ImportError when called from NASM but not from C

Tags: c, nasm, python-c-api

I call PyImport_Import to import the NLTK library.  When called from NASM as shown below it returns a null pointer and throws an ImportError, but when called from C as shown below it returns a valid pointer.  I get the same thing when importing Numpy -- it works when the C program is called by a C wrapper, but not when called by a NASM wrapper.

With NASM the error for nltk is "undefined symbol: PyTuple_Type."  For Numpy it's "undefined symbol: PyExc_RecursionError."  The full error message is for nltk shown below.

I need to call this from NASM because the project is written in NASM, but to help with finding the solution I also created the short C program to call it to see if that works when called from C, and it does.  I don't understand why is works when called from C but not when called from NASM as shown above.

The C program is linked into both the C and NASM versions.  The NASM program is a shared object and the C program is an .exe.  That distinction shouldn't matter because the NASM version works correctly if I load a Python built-in library like the math library.

With NASM it returns the following errors for nltk when I call PyErr_Print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py",    line 137, in <module>
    from nltk.text import *
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/text.py",     line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/ __init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize.casual import TweetTokenizer, casual_tokenize
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/ casual.py", line 49, in <module>
    import regex  # https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2409
  File  "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py",   line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File  "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/regex.py",  line 419, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py",     line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ImportError: /home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/    _regex.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol:    PyTuple_Type
18              return 1; }
(gdb)
```

The C program to call PyImport.Import:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int Lib_Gutenberg(char* module_name)
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule;

    Py_Initialize();
    int pii = Py_IsInitialized();

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module_name);

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule == 0x0){
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1; }

    return 0;
}
```

The NASM shared object that calls the C program shown above:

```
; Header Section
[BITS 64]

[default rel]

global Main_Entry_fn
global NLTK_Gutenberg_fn
extern Lib_Gutenberg
 
section .data align=64
 
section .rodata align=64
module_name: db 'nltk',0x00

section .text
 
Main_Entry_fn:

push rdi
push rbp
push rbx

lea rdi,[module_name]
call [rel Lib_Gutenberg wrt ..got]

NLTK_Gutenberg_fn:
mov rax,0
mov rbx,0

pop rbx
pop rbp
pop rdi
ret
```

The C wrapper (.exe) to call the same linked-in C program shown above:

```
#include "Lib_Gutenberg.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *  module_name = "nltk";

    int (*ptrGutenberg)(char*); 
    ptrGutenberg = Lib_Gutenberg;
    int result = (*ptrGutenberg)(module_name);
}
```

Lib_Gutenberg.h:

```
#ifndef LIB_GUTENBERG_H_   /* Include guard */
#define LIB_GUTENBERG_H_

int Lib_Gutenberg(char*);

#endif // LIB_GUTENBERG_
```

As I said above, the same NASM program works when I call the Python math library but not NLTK or Numpy.

Comment: The obvious difference between your C code and assembler is you have no equivalent to `#include <Python.h>` or `#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` shown. Not sure why one would call Python from assembly, but what I would do is dump the assembler generated by your C file and see what is happening there. Assuming gcc, it would be `gcc -S -masm=intel -std=C11 -O1 -o myC.asm myC.c` and then look though `myC.asm` and find out how it handles the include and define for python. You should also make sure you are not passing additional libraries to the linker when compiling your C code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The disassembly may be useful.  NASM does not call Python directly, it calls a C program (shown above) which is linked into the NASM program.  The C program contains the #include Python.h and the #define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN.

Comment: If this is an exercise to call python from assembler, that's fine, but if not and you have C and Python available to your for the hardware you are compiling for, then using assembly makes little sense. You use assembly to optimize a piece of code because the compiler doesn't do a good enough job for you. If you are calling python, then optimization isn't your goal. (it's like hooking a mule and plow to a Ferrari -- the assembler being the Ferrari). The other reason you would care about assembly is if there is no C or python that can run on your hardware, that's not your problem either.

Comment: Okay, I got you now. Check the disassembly. I suspect the linking of the assembler code is missing some of the library information that gets linked when you link with your test C program.

Comment: I generally write in NASM but I link in C programs that perform certain utilities better than NASM.  This C program calls the Python C API and returns to NASM.  We cannot use C header files in NASM, so where that's needed I link in a C utility program, as here.

Comment: I'll update this question if the disassembly shows the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried what you are doing, but to access functions in the Python C API though NASM, you will need to link against the python C API so when you make a function call in NASM, it can be found. Generally you would either have an `.obj` file for the python C API, or you would need to make a system call to load a dynamic library from within your assembler. I haven't used them, but the `__NR_uselib` syscall would be worth checking.